# Setting up server for iFolder

Tags: dropbox

I have two computers. A desktop at home and a netbook I use at school. I have grown so tired of having separate files on each system. I have tried sending mails to myself with attached files but it is very cumbersome and I always end up sending wrong/missing files.

I know of dropbox and skydrive but what I really want is to make my desktop computer accessible from outside. For this purpose I think iFolder fits me.

So my question goes - How do I make my desktop computer a server I can access outside my home?

It should be easy to use and I should be able to work from my desktop while it is running as a server?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the server from the relevant [repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/ifolder:/server_stable/), and the client is in the normal repository for openSuse, and there are downloads on the iFolder website for Windows and Mac.

There isn't room here to type out the details on how to set the whole thing up, [here](http://www.diwi.nl/node/50) is a short write up on how to do it,  or read the iFolder documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great setup guide here: http://www.daniellench.com/2010/08/ifolder-on-opensuse-11-3/